# NSevriceBus Assembly Version Error

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nservicebus, .net-assembly

I have an issue when trying to load the NServiceBus assembly from a client machine. The software runs correctly from my development box but once rolled out I get the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'NServiceBus, Version=2.0.0.1100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The weird thing is I am not using version 2.0.0.1100, I am using the latest version 2.0.0.1219. It seems to be referencing the old version somewhere but I cannot find where. I have set the “Specific Version” flag to true on both the NServiceBus & NServiceBus.Core assemblies and have tried to explicitly set the version number in the app config, both with no luck. I don’t understand why it works fine locally but errors once rolled out.  The project causing the error is a shared class library and it only appears to be erroring on some projects too.

Comment: Is CopyLocal = true or are you using the GAC?

Comment: did you try specifying binding redirects to the version you are using?